# How to update permissions for posting pictures to Facebook

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I develop a game with unity3d, I've integrated facebook's unity3d-SDK.
At login, I used

```
public void LoginFB()
{
    var perms = new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email","user_friends"};
    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);
}
```

But when I take a screenshot to post to facebook using :

```
FB.API("me/photos", HttpMethod.POST, ScreenshotSharePostCallBack, wwwForm);
```

The callback result said : 403 forbidden.

So I want to update the Permissions, but I have no idea about how to update it.

when I added the follow on the share button

```
FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions(new List<string>() { "publish_actions" }, callback : PublishActionsDone);
```

the app crashed.

Please tell me how to update the permissions when user click the button of sharing ,and how to open share dialog when using FB.API(.....).
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doens't work anymore. You have to use `FB.ShareLink()` now. which doesn't require any permission like "publish_actions" anymore. This now what Facebook prefers. BTW I forgot to mention you have to build it in order for it to work and see the results. :D

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.ShareLink